# Google Cloud Vision Product Search

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-product-search

I have some question about pricing in Product Search, documentation contains this term "Vision Product Search pricing is based on monthly usage for both queries and image management. Charges are incurred when you query a model, or maintain an image catalog via storage."

If that means charge is taking only when  I search similar products or when I search, and when I upload new product, image and update product? And table below is per image, not per request.

I want to see pricing table with any details of full process (create ProductSet, create product, add product to ProductSet, upload and storing image in bucket, add reference image to product, and search request)

Answer (score 0):

Product Search charges for prediction and storage of images: https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/pricing